# Add a conditional class to ul if it has no li children

Tags: html, css

How can I conditionally add a class to a ul if it has no li children?

I would like to use the syntax

`class=" @(myCondition == 1 ? "myClass" : "")"`

Comment: You need to use javascript, you can't do this in HTML

Comment: something I could do in document.ready then?

Comment: use the `:empty` pseudoclass

Comment: `:empty` does not work if whitespace or linebreaks are in the `<ul class="myClass">  </ul>`

Comment: Are you using a server side language? if so which one (looks like it might be c# with razor) and can you show how you create your li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".ul").forEach(el => el.classList += el.children.length ? " hasChildren" : "")
```

```css
.ul{
    background: lightskyblue;
    padding:1em;
    color: white;
}

.hasChildren{
    background-color: orangered;
}
```

```html
<ul class="ul">
  <li>Item</li>
</ul>

<ul class="ul">
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a JavaScript conditional, HTML/CSS isn't able to run that. What we can do instead is use script tags to use JavaScript to run the conditional.

```
class=" @(myCondition == 1 ? "myClass" : "")"
```

Can instead be written with JavaScript using Document object model to add classes to a element.

So what you might do instead is set the specific ul to an id of your choosing in the HTML.

```
<ul id="example">
```

Then we can add the JavaScript to the bottom of the `<body>`

```
<script>
  if(myCondition == 1){
      var ex = document.getElementById("example");
      ex.className += " myClass";
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <ul id="example"></ul>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery( document ).ready( function ()
    {
        if ( jQuery( "#example" ).children().length == 0 )
        {
            jQuery( "#example" ).addClass("myClass");
        }
    })
   </script>
```